# How best to wait for a RabbitMQ event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, integration-testing, microservices

I am writing integration events for my micro-service-based application, where services are decoupled an interact via a message bus such as RabbitMQ. For the integration tests, I use actual components and not mocking any component, hence I am using an actual RabbitMQ service.

One of my services subscribes to an event, when the event is fired, it does some process, and informs about the success of process. So, for testing it, the integration test should publish the event the service listens to, and wait for the services "success" event. (It makes more sense in the actual application, hence for the sake of clarity I've simplified it a bit, hence may sound a bit clumsy design.)

In short, the test is implemented as:

```cs
public class ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler: 
    IIntegrationEventHandler<ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent>
{
    public Task Handle(ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent @event)
    {
        // When I put a break point here, I can see this method is called 
        // after the service under the test has completed its task and has 
        // published the message.
    }
}

public class IntegrationTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task IfReceivesAndPublishesEvents()
    {
        // Arrange
        _rabbitMQBus.Subscribe<
              ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent,
              ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>();

        // Act
        Eventbus.Publish(new ProcessIntegrationEvent(name: "test"));

        // Assert
        // how should I assert if `ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler` is called?
    }
}
```

Question: what should add to the `Handle` method of the `ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler` and how check it in the test.

(For some reasons, I am not interested in assertions based on querying the RabbitMQ and checking if the related message is there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways how you could approach integration testing in these situations. Before doing that you should clarify what exactly are you testing?

**State has change?**

Are you testing a state change in some database(or storage) after your event has been processed? If yes then you could just fetch that state from the database and Assert if it has changed to the one that you expect. In this case you could be sure that the Handler has been called and your code has run. I would recommend you to use this approach if possible. In the end testing if RabbitMq works correctly is not needed.

**No state changes happen, but still you want to test if the Handler is executed?**

What you could do in this case is to use dependency injection and register another implementation of "IIntegrationEventHandler" interface. Lets call it "TestEventHandler". In the test setup you could use that implementation of "TestEventHandler" and just check if it has been called.

> Question: what should add to the Handle method of the
>   ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler and how check it in the test.

I would not advise to do this kind of test but if you really want to do that for some reason which is not clear to me from the information in the question you could do something like the TestEventHandler which has a property like:

```
public bool HandlerCalled { get; set; }
```

You would call the TestEventHandler's Handle method which would set this property to true and from this Handler you could call the ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler Handle method.

> (For some reasons, I am not interested in assertions based on querying
>   the RabbitMq and checking if the related message is there.)

In my opinion this would be a cleaner approach. Unless you have strong reasons not do it I would prefer this approach to the one with the HandlerCalled property because you are anyways not mocking RabbitMq.

Keep in mind that sometimes in micro-services architecture you can do integration tests like:

- test particular micro-service-A in isolation. Means you mock all the interactions with other micro-services. This has the advantage writing these kind of tests is easier and also that in your CI you do not have to setup multiple micro-services with all their dependent components(databases, queues and others).
- test full integration without mocking other micro-services. This means that you will setup in your CI all micro-services that are needed for particular test cases and interactions between them. The advantage is obviously that your tests are testing the full integration and are more realistic. On the other hand the disadvantage would be resource consumption of all the dependent components needed to perform those tests.

**EDIT:**

**First question**

To answer the follow up question how the HandlerCalled could be implemented?

Here is some pseudo code just to give an example:

```
public class ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler: 
    IIntegrationEventHandler<ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent>
{
    public Task Handle(ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent @event)
    {
        // Standard handler logic goes here
    }
}

public class TestEventHandler: 
    IIntegrationEventHandler<ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent>
{
    private readonly IIntegrationEventHandler<ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent> realHandler;
    public bool HandlerCalled { get; private set; }

    //This will be injected by the DI container
    public TestEventHandler(ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler realHandler)
    {
        this.realHandler = realHandler;
    }

    public Task Handle(ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent @event)
    {
        HandlerCalled = true;
        realHandler.Handle(@event)
    }
}

//here you would setup the Depdendency Injection and rest of he stuff regarding your services..
// this will depend on what you are using, ASP.NET Core or something else
public class BaseIntegrationTests
{
    protected IServiceCollection container;

    public BaseIntegrationTests()
    {
        //some setup code here.....
        RegisterDependencies();
    }

    //Register dependencies for DI Container
    private void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        container.AddScoped(ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler, TestEventHandler);

        //other registrations here ......
    }

    protected void RegisterTestEventHandlerInstance(TestEventHandler testEventHandler)
    {
        container.AddSingleton(IIntegrationEventHandler<ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent>, testEventHandler);
    }
}

public class IntegrationTests : BaseIntegrationTests
{
    private readonly TestEventHandler testEventHandler;

    public IntegrationTests()
    {
        //you could move this code here to the test if you want to use a different instance per test
        testEventHandler = new TestEventHandler();
        RegisterTestEventHandlerInstance(testEventHandler);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task IfReceivesAndPublishesEvents()
    {
        // Arrange
        _rabbitMQBus.Subscribe<
              ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent,
              ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>();

        // You would need to register dependecies if you use DI here
        // or in some central TestFixture class or similar
        // you would do something like

        //Check if the handler is not called yet, since the event has not been published
        Assert.False(testEventHandler.HandlerCalled);

        // Act
        Eventbus.Publish(new ProcessIntegrationEvent(name: "test"));

        // Assert 
        //if handler is called the flag should be true
        Assert.True(testEventHandler.HandlerCalled);
    }
}
```

**Second question**

> Also, regarding your first suggestion, could you give an example on
>   how to wait for a database record to be updated? (I am using EF).

This is a drawback of event based systems that you can not know exactly when it is going to be processed. But if your tests run on your local development machine and/or CI server you can predict that and do a couple of things to ensure you check the state afterwards(after the event has been processed).

What you could do is:

- Implement mechanism to wait for some time until you check for the state first time. You can predict this with some hard coded minimum latency time. For example you know for example that sending a message to RabbitMQ even if it is running on the same server will cost you for example 10ms(these are just random numbers, this has to be verified if its 10ms or some other value). On top of that receiving the event on the other side will for example also take 10ms. This way for example you know for sure that the event will not be processed before 20ms. This way you can always run your first check on the state in the database after this minimum latency period.
- Implement retry logic to get the data from some data store(database or similar). You could try multiple times with some delays. After some reasonable amount of times(which you need to define yourself) you could stop retrying.
- If you save the event that you are processing in your local micro-service database then you can check until it arrives there applying the previous 2 suggestions

In my experience having the minimum latency for running test on your development machine or on CI server will most of the time be fine and the event will be processed after that latency period. Having the retries helps most in some edge cases where for example the processing of the event takes longer.

Now coming to the question how you could achieve this? There are many ways. One way would be if you would create a wrapper class around your Eventbus for Integration tests. Every time you publish an event after the event has been published you could just stop the thread for the minimum latency period:

```
[Fact]
public async Task IfReceivesAndPublishesEvents()
{
    // Arrange
    _rabbitMQBus.Subscribe<
          ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent,
          ProcessCompletedIntegrationEventHandler>();

    // You would need to register dependecies if you use DI here
    // or in some central TestFixture class or similar
    // you would do something like

    // Act
    EventbusIntegrationTest.Publish(new ProcessIntegrationEvent(name: "test"));

    // Assert 
    //Assert state has changed ....
}

public static class EventbusIntegrationTest
{
    private static int minimumLatency = 20;

    public static void Publish(Event @event)
    {
        Eventbus.Publish(@event);
        // after each published event you will wait at least the minimum latency time 
        // before doing any other action
        Task.Delay(minimumLatency).Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how a method similar to `HandlerCalled` can be implemented? an example can be very much useful.

Comment: Also, regarding your first suggestion, could you give an example on how to wait for a database record to be updated? (I am using EF).

Comment: I edited my answer with answers to your questions. If it is helpful for you please up-vote/accept the answer.

Comment: I cannot get this line working: `container.AddSingleton(IIntegrationEventHandler<ProcessCompletedIntegrationEvent>, testEventHandler);` More specifically, how do you set `IServiceCollection container`?

Comment: It was pseudo code. There is some Integration test setup needed additionaly. That is not in scope of this question. The container should do the registrations in Startup.cs. If you have a dedicated cproj for Integration tests you could have a separate Startup.cs for setting up DI container there. There are a lot of materials online about Asp.net core Integration test setup with custom Startup.cs.

Comment: If you need help or examples on that I can help you.

Comment: thank you. I used a little different approach for that type registration using `ConfigureWebHost` method in my implementation of `IClassFixture`. (Basically, similar to what you mentioned for host setup for tests.)